# scaling svg to parent container

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am using svg.js to draw lines on like a canvas. Is it possible to scale the svg element created by calling SVG() to the size of the parent? As of right now, I am just redrawing all the lines when the element resizes.

```
<div
  ref={r => this.whiteboard = r}
  id="whiteboard"
  >
</div>
{...}
let { offsetWidth: width, offsetHeight: height } = this.whiteboard;
this.draw = SVG('whiteboard').size(width, height);
```

I am using React which I know will be hard to mix with svg.js but that is another conversation.

Comment: post your code here !

Comment: Without your code it's not clear, but i suspect you're missing a viewBox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Comment: I just added all the svg.js related code

Comment: I know it's an awful answer, but have you looked into this extension ? : https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.resize.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Looking at it now, looks like only elements inside draw = SVG('drawing') can be resized, but I need draw and it's contents to resize

Answer (score 1):

Use SVG.ViewBox

http://svgjs.dev/geometry/#svg-viewbox

For example, something like:

```
this.draw = SVG('whiteboard').size(width, height).viewbox(0,0,500,300);
```

The actual values you pass will depend on what you are drawing, and where it is on the canvas.  The `viewBox()` parameters are: minX, minY, width, and height.

Comment: getting "TypeError: this.draw.viewBox is not a function". The method is actually viewbox. Everything is scaling, but they are also moving as the parent resizes. e.g. Initially there's a square in the corner. As the parent gets smaller, the square gets smaller, but it also translates to the right.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have fixed my answer.  Smaller how?  Post an example.  That behaviour may be correct, depending on how you are resizing the parent.  [Read about how viewBox and preserveAspectRatio works, ](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#coords-ViewBoxAttribute)

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you need to scale or translate the visible area of your svg use viewbox. A good article to learn more is https://www.justinmccandless.com/post/making-sense-of-svg-viewboxs-madness/